# How to write a ReactJS high order component using ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, high-order-component

I´m trying to build a ReactJS high order component using ES6 syntax. Here is my try:

```
export const withContext = Component =>
    class AppContextComponent extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <AppContextLoader>
                     <AppContext.Consumer>
                        {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
                    </AppContext.Consumer>
               </AppContextLoader>
            );
        }
    };
```

Here, `AppContextLoader` gets context from database and provide it to the context, as:

```
class AppContextLoader extends Component {
  state = {
    user: null,
  };

  componentWillMount = () => {
    let user = databaseProvider.getUserInfo();
    this.setState({
      user: user
      });
  };


  render = () => {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  };
}

export default AppContextLoader;
```

And usage:

```
class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
         title: PropTypes.string,
         module: PropTypes.string
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
                withContext(
                <Dashboard
                    module={this.props.module}
                    title={this.props.title}
                />
                );

export default App;
```

For some reason my wrapped component (`Dashboard`) is not getting my `context` property, just the original ones (`title` and `module`).

How to properly write HOC using ES6 syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the HOC correctly, you need to pass the component and not the component instance. Also invoking the HOC from within render is a bad patten since each render a new component will be returned, you must write

```
const DashboardWithContext = withContext(Dashboard);
class App extends Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
                <DashboardWithContext
                    module={"ADMIN"}
                    title={"MY APP"}
                />
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Also in `withContext HOC` since the returned component is a class, you would  access props like `{...this.props}` instead of `{...props}`, However it makes sense to use a functional component since you aren't actually using the lifecycle methods

```
 export const withContext = Component => (props) => (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        );
```

**[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6yq8qpl4p)**

Comment: Still not working for me... I will make changes on post, as in real life `Dashboard` passed properties are tied to App properties... Check the edited code.

Comment: Do you have a provider wrapping the App component

Comment: Please check this codesandbox based on your code,  https://codesandbox.io/s/z6yq8qpl4p

Answer (score 0):

It should be `this.props` instead:

```
<Component {...this.props}
```

This should be working for you:

```
render() {
  const props = this.props;
  return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

1. You're not using the Context API properly - the context is created for the use of a `Provider` to share a value to one or many `Consumers` - you are creating with the hoc a new `Provider` and `Consumer`.
2. from your example, you don't need to use `Context` - use an hoc for new use data - `withUserData`
3. You should use `this.props` and not props
4. In the usage section, you pass to the hoc an element and not a component
5. You're not getting the props from `withContext`

**Solution**

```
export const withUserData = BaseComponent =>
  class AppContextLoader extends Component {
    state = {
      user: null,
    };

    componentWillMount = () => {
      let user = databaseProvider.getUserInfo();
      this.setState({
        user: user
      });
    };


    render = () => {
      return (
        <BaseComponent {...this.props} {...this.state} />
      );
    };
  }
```

And usage:

```
class App extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
         title: PropTypes.string,
         module: PropTypes.string
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
                  <EnhancedDashboard
                    module={this.props.module}
                    title={this.props.title}
                  />
                );
     }


const EnhancedDashboard = withUserData(Dashboard)

export default App;
```